# How to check if an element from an ArrayList is equal to a certain value?

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, switch-statement

I have an ArrayList list1 which contains the following values: {"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B"}.

I want to count how many times each of the letters (A, B and C) repeat in list1.

I have done the following, but the result is 0.

```
for (i=0; i<=list1.size(); i++) {
    switch (list1.get(i)) {
        case "A":
            LetterA = LetterA + 1;
        case "B":
            LetterB = LetterB + 1;
        case "C":
            LetterC = LetterC + 1;
    }
}

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Letter A repeats: " + LetterA + " times" + "\nLetter B repeats: " + LetterB + " times" + 
"\nLetterC repeats: " + LetterC + " times", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

UPDATE: The problem was that I accidentally looped through list1 instead of list2, which actually contained the letters. However, even when I changed this, it still showed incorrect values. Therefore I changed the `switch` to this:

```
for (i=0; i<=list2.size(); i++) {
    if (list2.get(i).equals("A")) {
        LetterA = LetterA + 1;
    } else if (list2.get(i).equals("B")) {
        LetterB = LetterB + 1;
    } else if (list2.get(i).equals("C")) {
        LetterC = LetterC + 1;
    }
}
```

Now everything works perfectly.

Comment: how you initialized ArrayList or how you added items to arrayList ?

Comment: It is initialized as an empty ArrayList. `ArrayList<String> list1;` It is a very long piece of code. I have added these elements into the arraylist through various sets of conditions, and then displayed everything in a ListView. Everything works fine. If I display the ArrayList or try to display the size of the ArrayList in the Toast it shows the actual size. The problem is, however, that I don't know if `get(i)` is correct. I think that might be the problem. But I don't know what to change it with.

Comment: So basically you are getting what values after loop ? are those all zeros ?

Comment: Yes. I get only 0 for all of them.

Comment: Your code should have to crash because you are using i=0; i<=list1.size(); i++ it will throw IndexOutOfBound exception I think you are putting it in try catch block are you ?

Comment: Oops. I should try `list1.size() - 1` I'll return and tell you what I got.

Comment: No that won't solve problem also ... it will still give you zero If I am not wrong Yeah update me after checking it

Comment: @PraveenSP Yes, it still gives 0 :((((

Comment: I am assuming it's not getting in the loop itself ... Can't you post complete code ? I recommend to do so ..if possible

Comment: @PraveenSP Thank you very much for your help. I found the problem and now everything works fine. It seems I was not very careful to the list I used. But that was not the only problem. Nested if's worked better than the switch statement.

Comment: You are welcome Johnny and don't forget to use break; after cases when you use switch next time :) happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
        Map<String, Long> counted = list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(counted);
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume OP is using API level 24+?